# Uploading static files to Keystone.js

Tags: keystonejs

I'm evaluating potential content management systems I want to use for a project. Many of the users will need to upload static files and include links to the in their posts.

In the Admin UI I can only see the ability to upload an image in a post. Does anyone know if it is possible to upload files to Keystone through the Admin UI?

Answer (score 0):

You could use their Amazon S3 storage adapter. Depending on which version of Keystone you're using (3 or 4), you'll have to do some different things. Either way, you need to make some credentials for [Amazon S3's service](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and [configure Keystone to work with it](http://keystonejs.com/docs/configuration/#services-amazons3). From there, you can use `Types.S3File` to allow a certain part of your MongoDB model to be a reference to an S3 object. See [this page](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fieldtypes-s3file) for more info on the `S3File` type in Keystone.